# Core data filtering result

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

Are there any methods to sorting (filtering) result.

For example I have database which contain some information:

```
alex - 21,
bob  - 65,
roy  - 37,
alex - 55;
```

I want to get result like this (like NSMutableArray):

```
alex - (21, 55),
bob - 65,
roy - 55;
```

I can do it using loop, but may be it's possible by native instruments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this, each "object" so, "alex", "bob", "roy" and "alex" are different, so when you fetch a set of objects, it gives you your set, "alex" is different from the other "alex", an easier way to simulate something like this would to have a to-many relationship set between what I assume is a Person entity and an, Age entity ?

If your Alex's are in fact the same person, which thinking of it in the context of my example seems impossible, you could retrieve only 3 objects and for each retrieve another information from it's to-many relationship.

A better example may be a game for which each user has a set of scores, thus grouping a score in a to-many relationship.